# What is the relationship of IoC and AOP?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, aop

I am reading spring docs [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core) site.

and I already have knowledge IoC(or DI) and AOP a little bit.

While reading docs, I read this phrase.

> Foremost amongst these is the Spring Framework’s Inversion of Control (IoC) container. A thorough treatment of the Spring Framework’s IoC container is closely followed by comprehensive coverage of Spring’s Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) technologies.

As far as I know, IoC is how Container creates instances and injects them when needed, and AOP is perspective-oriented programming;How you can focus on what you want to do.

However, I understand the above phrase that AOP works well thanks to IoC.

I'm not sure what's the relationship between the two.

Wait for a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An **IoC** framework allows **injection of an implementation through an external influence**, typically configuration.

**AOP**'s purpose is to enable loose **weaving of other concerns into business logic code without direct modification of the code**.

Spring is a framework that extensively uses AOP to enable implementation of IoC.

There is a whole lot of reading material on both patterns available on the web.
For IoC start [here](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). For AOP, I found [this](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-spring-aop-1) helpful.

Comment: I will not write another answer because this is not a question suited for SO anyway, but I want to comment on this accepted one: AOP and IoC are **orthogonal, unrelated concepts** both of which happen to be implemented and used by Spring as tools for developing enterprise applications. For example, AspectJ is completely independent of Spring or any other container, you can use in in any JVM application. So you can use AOP without IoC or dependency injection. It is also possible to use an IoC design pattern without AOP. So don't mix up the concepts just because Spring uses both.

Answer (score 1):

AOP concerned mainly with abstracting functionality that applies across the board to many components of your application. for example logging and security. These have little or nothing to do with actual business functionality but are essential system-wide functions

IOC or Di is mainly loose coupling and managing the dependencies between the component of an application.

Comment: You might use AOP for transaction handling or eventing.  So I'm not sure the big distinction is between business logic and other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Both IOC and AOP are made possible through having your code managed by some sort of run-time container.

The container injects dependencies into your constructors and property setters, instead of you doing it manually. The motto for Spring is/was: "Creating objects so you don't have to."

Once your code is running in a container, it's a simple enough matter to introduce AOP concepts which boil down to executing code before or after what's being managed by the container.

IOC and AOP are sibling practices made possible by a run-time container. Start with a IOC container and it's easy to introduce AOP features. Start with an AOP container and IOC features easily follow.